# Perl Printf Two Strings with Specified Length Between

Tags: perl, printf

I am printing a string that needs formatting. I would like to printf with a set number of characters I have stored in another variable but I am not sure how to do this.

```
my $max_len = max map length, keys %hash;
printf ("%s %s\n", $string1, ":$string2");
```

Obviously this is outputting `string1 :string2` but what I want is for the total width of the first column to be $max_len. How can I do this?

Comment: The space *between*, or the total width of the first column?

Comment: @hobbs oh yes. the total width of the first column!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%-4s` will pad the value by appending spaces until it takes up four characters.

```
my $max_len = max map length, keys %hash;

for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
    printf("%-{$max_len}s %s\n", $key, $hash{$key})
}
```

You can use `*` to tell `printf` to use a parameter as the field width.

```
my $max_len = max map length, keys %hash;

for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
    printf("%*s %s\n", -$max_len, $key, $hash{$key})
}
```

or

```
my $max_len = max map length, keys %hash;

for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
    printf("%-*s %s\n", $max_len, $key, $hash{$key})
}
```

Comment: thanks! if i wanted to create a fixed length for the second column as well, could I do `printf ("%*s %s %*s %s %s\n", -$max_len, $string1, -$max_len_2, $string2, $string3);`?

Comment: No, `"%*s %*s %s"`